# I downloaded a SQL Server file, but it is not saving data from my PC

Tags: c#, sql-server, angularjs, angular, api

I created a API with Angular frontend, for the back end I created a SQL Server table. However, I did this all on a different PC and it was working perfectly there. I downloaded the SQL file to my other laptop and executed it. I have put breakpoints in my application and can see that the code ran smoothly, but the data wasn't saved to SQL.

The application is a calculator, the user makes calculations on the Angular website, the API takes that info and sends to SQL server that stores all the data.

**Code**

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<bool> AddRecord([FromBody] Calculation calculation)
        {
            return await service.AddRecord(calculation);
        }

    }
}
```

Calculator Service file

```
public interface ICalculatorService 
    {
        Task<bool> AddRecord(Calculation calculation);
    
    }

    public class CalculatorService : ICalculatorService
    {
        private readonly DemoCalculatorContext context;

        public CalculatorService(DemoCalculatorContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public async Task<bool> AddRecord(Calculation calculation)
        {
            context.Calculation.Add(calculation);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return calculation.CalculationId > 0 ? true : false;
        }
    }
```

CalculationID is a boolean and it is automatically assigns a number when data is saved and gives a 0 when it is not saved. My breakpoint has all the info from the calculation made on the website, so I know the Angular website and API are communicating fine. There is something wrong with SQL server. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Check connection string. Also if it is mssql/mysql - did you attach database to your server?

Comment: Check connection string, and use `try catch` for catch exception.

Comment: SQL Server isn't a data file, you have to install SQL Server and then either attach your database file (not recommended) or restore your backup file.